# Doctrine 2 - Can't set composite primary key named "id"

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm writing at the moment a fixture loader command, where i generate a mysql-database with orm.yml-files and loading database fixture afterwards. At the moment the loader command is working fine for tables with a simple primary key. But now I have a table, which consists of a composited primary key (of three columns). Two Columns ("id" and "language") are foreign keys to another tables (with a 1:n relationship).

I'm getting this error message, when I make the fixture loader command call:

```
Message: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO xyzInt (id, language, name, text, update, userID, complete) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [null, "com", "peter", "text", "2017-03-06 18:00:00", 1, 0]:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'update, userID, complete) VALUES (NULL, 'com', 'peter', 'text', '2017-03-' at line 1
```

And my xyzInt.orm.yml looks like this:

```
Entity\Xyzint:
  type: entity
  table: xyzInt

  id:
    id:        { type: integer, options: { default: 0, unsigned: true }, generator: { strategy: NONE } }
    language:  { type: string, length: 2, options: { default: '' }, generator: { strategy: NONE } }
    name:      { type: string, length: 30, options: { default: '' }, generator: { strategy: NONE } }

  fields:
    ...

  manyToOne:
    Abc:
      targetEntity: Abc
      inversedBy: Xyzint
      joinColumn:
        name: id
        referencedColumnName: abcID
```

And now i've got two questions:

1. why is field "id" not set correctly (it remains null)?
2. Is the manyToOne-correlation made correctly for a composite primary key? Or must i use "joinColumns" instead of "joinColumn"? And when i have
   to use "joinColumns" can you give me a short example, how the
   orm.yml-configuration should look like? I couldn't find the correct
   answer in google until now.

Thanxs for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with following solution:
In the table xyzInt i've added a new column, which is used as THE NEW simple primary key now. The value of the new column is a combination of id, language and name. And the columns id, language and name are now normal columns, which are indexed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not confortable with Yaml but I think you should set your generation strategy to auto. Something like this :

```
id:        { type: integer, options: { default: 0, unsigned: true }, generator: { strategy: AUTO } }
```

Change `strategy: NONE` to `strategy: AUTO`

Here is the doc for YAML config : 
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/yaml-mapping.html

Comment: Thanxs for your answer. But i want to set individually the field "id" with no auto generated special values. Therefore i use `$connection->query('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');`

Comment: Additional note: It should be allowed that for one "id" there can exists more database entries. So an auto generated "id" makes no sense.

Comment: why bother setting yourself the id when doctrine can do it for you ? In your second comment are you actually meaning that an id can match multiple entries ? Anyway, your question was why the id is null, it's because you don't provide correctly a value for it. You can do it automatically as in my answer or check on Google how to do it manually using YAML.

Comment: I want to make some functional tests with this separate database, which consists only of test data. But the functional tests will only working, if the column id from the table xyzint is set individually. Because the functional test makes e.G. some checks, when id 12345 is there. So i can't autogenerate it.

Comment: And yes an id can match multple entries.

Comment: I think - but I can be wrong - that you are confusing an id which must be unique (it's like object's DNA) and a field which can be 12345 for several object. Of course, you can achieve what you have described with the id but it's not its role. Anyway, like I said, just provide a value for the id in your fixture and you have to also manage the id of associated objects... I highly recommend you to let doctrine do his job and define another field with 12345 or whatever, but the decision is yours

Comment: But that's why only a composite primary key (here with columns "id","language","name") makes a database entry unique, not only an entry with id "12345". The problem is that the database exists already and is a legacy system which wasn't generated with doctrine. And the new database should be a copy with the same database structure. That's why i must set some values (like the ids) individually, so the functional tests are working correctly later.